# How do I add a second action (segue) to a UIAlertAction action?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

Please excuse me, i'm relatively new to ios coding:

I have implemented an actionSheet with "Cancel" and "Buy" buttons. The Buy button action executes successfully, no problem.

But, what I want to do, is add another (2nd) action that lets user automatically segue to another screen after the original (1st) action is called.

Simplified: I want to press the Buy button (on my actionSheet) which downloads product, and then want to be automatically taken to the download screen to see my new downloads.

```
private func setBuyButton() -> Void {

    // Buy button action sheet
    actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "CONFIRM PURCHASE", message: "\(self.products.title) will be added to your Download page", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let confirmPurchase = UIAlertAction(title: "Buy", style: .default) { action in

        var productList = [String: Bool]()
        let productSetName = [self.productSetId : true]

        self.product.map({ (drop: Drop) -> Void in
            productList[product.productKey] = true
        })

        if let userId = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: KEY_UID) {
            let downloads = ["product": productList, "productset": productSetName]
            DataService......blah, blah, blah...

        }
    }

    actionSheet.addAction(confirmPurchase)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancel)
}
```

Comment: Just insert the line for the segue after the download process complete or may in completion handler if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With a programmatically.

Create a file `DownloadView` with the subclass of `UICollectionViewController`, then in your action add these code

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let controller = DownloadView.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Also, if you don't need a `collectionView`, create a file with subclass of `UIViewController` and push it like this

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DownloadView(), animated: true)
```

#### With Storyboard

Add viewController with identifer `down` and write these code in action handler

```
let downloadView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "down") as! DownloadView
self.present(downloadView, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Thanks Picker ! I used the 3rd option (with Storyboard), Working nicely!

Comment: Yourwellcom, please check the correct answer to find easy by others

Comment: Hi Picker, I just noticed that while the code is working and shows the correct screen, It is not changing and hi-lighting the UITabBar Icon / item of the screen i've segued to, How do i change the selected TabBar icon? 
**The Code**:
let myProductsView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyProductsVC") as! MyProductsVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myProductsView, animated: false)

Comment: The rootViewController should have a navigation controller, storyboard click the first screen-->edit-->embedin-->navigationController

Answer (score 1):

In your storyboard, control click the yellow circle icon above the view controller and drag to the destination view controller to create a segue.
[image: Create segue]
Select the segue and give it an identifier
[image: Give your segue an identifier]

Now you can call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` in your first view controller to segue programatically. In your case, put

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourCustomSegue", sender: nil)
```

in your row action handler will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I'm very grateful Ricky, but I know how to create segues with IDs, I just wasn't sure where to put the code and if i needed some declaration. I have since figured that out with the help of @KrunalNagvadia 's answer. Thanks guys!

**Here's a follow-on question**: Do i need to create a new segue, if the screen i'm going to is part of the UITabBarController? Can I just do the segue somehow through the UITabBarController? again pls note, i'm not advanced in coding, so my questions may be a bit low level.

Comment: You can segue to the `UITabBarController`, pass the information about which tab you want to select via `prepare(for:sender:)`, then select the right tab in `viewDidLoad` of the `UITabBarController` by changing `selectedIndex`.

Comment: Ok thanks Ricky, I'll try figure that out later today.

Comment: Hey @Ricky, I'm forced to up-skill myself in Swift and I'm looking for a tutor for about two hour per week, Is this something you do or would consider? Thanks

Comment: @Jamakes Nope, I'm not a tutor :-)